# Disable user shell for security reasons

Tags: shell, ssh, users, login

We have several user accounts that we create for automated tasks that require fine-grained permissions, such as file transfer across systems, monitoring, etc.

How do we lock down these user accounts so that these "users" have no shell and are not able to login? We want to prevent the possibility that someone can SSH in as one of these user accounts.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use the `usermod` command to change a user's login shell.

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin myuser
```

or

```
usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin myuser
```

If your OS does not provide /sbin/nologin, you can set the shell to a NOOP command such as /bin/false:

```
usermod -s /bin/false myuser
```

Comment: `/bin/false` seems more common than `/bin/true`.

Comment: @jw013 I update my answer, but both should work fine.

Comment: Note that on Debians, `nologin` actually is to be found at `/usr/sbin/nologin`

Comment: this was my first idea, unfortunately the 'valid' use of some user accounts are disabled when setting `nologin`

Comment: @javier in that case you can use a restricted shell such as `rssh`.

Comment: @jw013 Actually I have `/usr/local/bin/maybe` which `/dev/urandom`ly selects between those two. Maybe I should use it :D

Answer (score 25):

Changing the login shell does not necessarily prevent users from authenticating (except in some services that check if the user's shell is mentioned in `/etc/shells`).

People may still be able to authenticate to the various services that your system provides to unix users, and may still be authorized to perform some actions albeit probably not run arbitrary commands directly.

Changing the shell to `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` will only prevent them from running commands on those services that can be used to run commands (console login, ssh, telnet, rlogin, rexec...), so affect *authorisation* for some services only.

For `ssh` for instance, that still allows them to do port forwarding.

`passwd -l` will disable password authentication, but the user may still be allowed to use other authentication methods (like `authorized_keys` with `ssh`).

With `pam` on Linux at least, you can use the `pam_shells` module to restrict authentication or authorisation to users with an allowed shell (those mentioned in `/etc/shells`). For `ssh`, you'll want to do it at authorisation (`account`) level as for authentication `sshd` uses `pam` *in addition* to other authentication methods (like `authorized_keys`), or you can do it with `sshd_config` directives in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (like `AllowUsers` and friends).

Beware though that adding some restrictions in global pam authorisation will potentially prevent running `cron` jobs as those users.

Comment: Thank you. Then what would you recommend given the following schema: I need to create a user who need access to his home folder through sftp or sshfs, but he must not be able to login with a shell. Is that even possible ? I fell like PAM modules may be the goto solution but I do not understand it all `:|`

Comment: @Stphane you can take a look at rssh - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rssh.1.html

Answer (score 6):

First, disable the password, using `passwd -l username`.

Also note in the `man` page for `passwd` for option `-l`:

```
   -l, --lock
       Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no
       possible encrypted value (it adds a Â´!Â´ at the beginning of the password).

       Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token
       (e.g. an SSH key). To disable the account, administrators should use usermod --expiredate 1 (this set the account's
       expire date to Jan 2, 1970).

       Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.
```

Comment: This may not be desirable. They may need a password on their system account to access email for example.

Comment: Some email systems allow use of their own password mechanisms.  I use Dovecot and Exim with an email only password.  This allows use of webmail on servers I would not use my system password.  Virtual email domains require their own password as they aren't coupled to the servers password system.

Comment: All of the other answers disable also ssh access for me, hence this is the only answer that accurately answers the OP's requirements! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You edit the `/etc/passwd` file and change the users shell from `/bin/bash`, or `/bin/sh` to `/sbin/nologin`

Comment: The answer is correct, but hand-editing /etc/passwd should never be recommended.

Comment: Why? This is something we've been doing for as long as I've been a professional sys admin. (about 20 years now) In fact, not all linux/unix distros have tools for modifying /etc/passwd or /etc/group .. Unless you use something like Yast or Smit, which are tools that cache the settings and over-write them there is no harm in hand editing.

Comment: It's much easier to make a "breaks everyone's login" mistake by hand-editing, rather than a single user.

Comment: @jordanm: there is `vipw` which prevents that kind of mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use chsh command:

```
~# chsh myuser
```

Enter new shell details when requested:

```
Login Shell [/bin/sh]: /bin/nologin
```

Or shorter version:

```
~# chsh myuser -s /bin/nologin
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent user from logging and even authentication over ssh that enables port forwarding (as is described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174855/176050) Stephane), I modify the user to be similar to system's `nobody` user:

- blocked password authentication in `/etc/shadow` (with `*` or `!!` at proper field)
- disabled shell in `/etc/passwd` (e.g. `/sbin/nologin` at proper field)
- read-only home dir in `/etc/passwd` (e.g. `/` at proper field)