# can I set up openssh-server on local machine without messing my git ssh access to git and gerrit server?

Tags: git

We have git/ gerrit ssh on local machine (~/.ssh/id_rsa id_rsa.pub known_hosts    + ssh-agent )

Now we want to access local machine from multiple remote clients (4-5 users, 1 user at a time), 
to download latest code and run scripts.

Can I set up openssh-server on same  machine without messing up our ssh access to git/ gerrit servers?

Answer (score 0):

The same openssh-server, which you already use for Git, can be used for any remote access. You just need to create user accounts and possibly setup ssh key pairs for remote users, just like you have already created key pairs for Git usage.

One thing to mention: for downloading the latest code, one doesn't need to have shell access - SFTP is enough i.e. for those users, shell can be disabled (see [Disable user shell for security reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55106/disable-user-shell-for-security-reasons) for more information). But for running scripts, shell access is needed.

Comment: Yes, I would need to run scripts and also run applications that require 'window system' for GUI..

Comment: Please check X2Go - it provides you remote access to X "windowing system".

Answer (score 0):

Installing openssh-server on a machine that is already set up as an SSH client will not affect its functionality as a client.