# Is it safe to disable shell access to all users listed in /etc/passwd?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, users

I have just read about how to disable shell access for users in Ubuntu [in this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55113/149288) for security reasons. Is it safe to disable shell access to all users listed in `/etc/passwd` except the `root:x:0:0` and another specific user, say `tom:x:1000:1000`?

For example, if I disable shell for the default users coming with the installation of the operating system such as `daemon`, `bin`, `sys`, `sync`, `games`, `man`, `lp`, `mail`, `news`, and `uucp` (and many others not listed here), may this cause any issue?

Comment: No, you shouldn't, because it may be required by certain programs and may later be needed to repair damage to the account.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's safe, since there may be programs that require it, but I do know it's not necessary. These users already have login access disabled by way of not having passwords, so there's no need to change the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In /etc/passwd almost all users seem to be assigned /bin/bash or /bin/sh, but that does not mean they have shell access as they don't have passwords. Is this right?

Comment: Not quite. Even without a valid password, I can `su` to the `bin` user from root and get shell access. I have no direct login access to the `bin` user, though, which is what is important.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the login shell. It is already disabled wherever it is not needed , you can see it is something like `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false`

Only root has the shell `/bin/bash` or some other user account that we ourselves create for longing in into the system.

Comment: As I just commented to John's answer, almost all of the default users (which were not created by us) are assigned to either /bin/bash or /bin/sh. I never changed the shells for these users since the installation of the OS. Does that mean that those shell assignments are deafult and needed for the OS?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple.

These users like `daemon`, `bin`, `sys`, `sync`, `games`, `man`, `lp`, `mail`, `news`, and `uucp` are not interactive users. They are intended for some special perposes, like running a daemon(web server for example), and are not intended to run another program.

So basically they shouldn't have interactive shell.