# How to disable SFTP for a user, but keep FTP enabled

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I've created a user called "ftp-acc" and limited it to a single directory using VSFTPD. When I login to the account in Filezilla using FTP, it is successfully restricted to a single directory.

However, when logging in with the same credentials using SFTP, the user can access other directories as well.

How can I disable SFTP for the user "ftp-acc"?

Comment: Don't give the user [a valid shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55113/13796).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First point , FTP and SFTP both are different. FTP normal file transfer protocol but SFTP is secure file transfer protocol and this service is from SSH not a stand alone service.

If you want to disable SFTP for one user then open sshd_config file in server(machine you are trying to access) and

```
DenyUsers ftp-acc
```

and then restart sshd service with

`service sshd restart`