# Preventing users from sudo'ing to the root user

Tags: sudo, root, su

I'm searching for a way to prevent my system users to sudo into the root account in any way.

I don't mean logging to the root user by SSH, but specifically by sudoing ( sudo -s ) ( sudo su ) etc.

Any suggestions?

(Expect white listing specific commands by sudoers file )

Thanks!

[image: Thats what i want to prevent. when user uses "sudo -s" he will not be able to use the "root" user]

Comment: Do you still want users to be able to use `sudo` to act as other non-root users?

Comment: Yes, The users have sudo access to run privileged commands. the idea behind disabling sudo into root user is to find suspicous activities.when you implement your employees the idea of using sudo for every command, suspicious activity can be easier to find :)

Comment: Ah, so you're talking about being able to start an _interactive root shell_, only.

Comment: I found this one : http://makeitcompliant.blogspot.com/2012/06/restricting-root-shell-and-root-user.html that is actually my question "Users often drop to a root shell to avoid typing sudo before any command. Dropping to a root shell is usually done doing su -, sudo –i, sudo –s, sudo bash etc." what i want is to prevent my users from dropping into the "root" shell. the example on this website is not working. any suggetions?

Answer (score 5):

Once you define the sudoers specification with the 'ALL' keyword in the commands field, there is no way to effectively prevent the execution of a specific command or set of commands. The [sudoers manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.27/sudoers.man.html#SECURITY_NOTES) explains this in a straightforward manner:

> Limitations of the ‘!’ operator
>
> It is generally not effective to “subtract” commands from ALL using
>   the ‘!’ operator. A user can trivially circumvent this by copying the
>   desired command to a different name and then executing that. For
>   example:
>
> `bill ALL = ALL, !SU, !SHELLS`
>
> Doesn't really prevent bill from running the commands listed in SU or
>   SHELLS since he can simply copy those commands to a different name, or
>   use a shell escape from an editor or other program. Therefore, these
>   kind of restrictions should be considered advisory at best (and
>   reinforced by policy).
>
> In general, if a user has sudo ALL there is nothing to prevent them
>   from creating their own program that gives them a root shell (or
>   making their own copy of a shell) regardless of any ‘!’ elements in
>   the user specification.

The only way to avoid the scenario described above is to have a list of allowed commands that the user can execute, i.e. a whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, because there is always a way to act as root as long as you do not white list specific commands in the sudoers file.

If you don't mind disabling the root login shell completely, you could [disable the user shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55113/197803).

It would still be possible for any sudo user to undo this of course.

Comment: using this method disables SSH access but no preventing users from using " sudo -s" to su into the root user

Answer (score 0):

Remove the users from the `sudo` group and create a new group, say, `restricted`.

Then, in `/etc/sudoers` (or better yet, in a file under `/etc/sudoers.d`) you add something like this:

```
%restricted ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/command1,/etc/init.d/command2 restart
```

The users in that group will only be able to run those commands.

Comment: Hi, That was not my question :)

Comment: You're right. Sorry.

Comment: This new answer might solve it.

Comment: `/usr/bin/rsync`?  Hopefully you won't be surprised when someone you gave the ability to run `rsync` as root to uses that to get full root privileges.  "Gee, I have root `rsync`!!!!  I can copy `/etc/shadow` out, change or remove the root password, and copy it back!"

Comment: @AndrewHenle that is not an actual entry. But I'll edit it so as to not distract people from the actual solution.

Comment: Guys i think that you have not got the point, i didn't say that there is no way of breaking out of this "jail" or whatever we call that, but i just say that if every user will know that this is disabled, when attacker will come and try to sudo into the root user, i will have an alert for this(already have a rule for that), but i cannot go to each user and tell them" dont sudo into root" because that will take years.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same so this is what I tried and worked

Created a group called `admin` and then added `admin` group to `etc/sudoers`

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
admin ALL=(ALL)ALL, !SHELLS, !SU
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

# usermod -aG admin u3
# usermod -aG wheel u3

# su - u3

[u3@localhost ~]$ yum install something
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
You need to be root to perform this command.

[u3@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install something
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
```

So the user `u3` has the root power since added to the `wheel` group but it will not get root shell so sysadmin will know what `u3` has been done with the sudo/root privilege.

Comment: Any user in your `admin` group can get a shell. If you read some of the other answers to this question they explain why your suggestion is flawed - as does the man page itself